# Automapper - how to apply ForMember configuration at a deep level

Tags: c#, model, automapper, viewmodel, object-object-mapping

I am trying to learn asp.NetCore 2.2. I am trying to setup a simple one page site. I have run into a problem with Automapper where manual Mappinng using forMember() is working at a top level for `CreateMap<Listing, ListingSearchResultsDto>().ForMember(ListingPhotosUrl)` but not at a lower level. I have another mapping `CreateMap<User, UserDetailsDto>()` where `user` contains an object `Mylistings` of type `Listing`. `Mylistings` is correctly auto mapped to `ListingSearchResultsDto` but manual configuration `CreateMap<Listing, ListingSearchResultsDto>().ForMember(ListingPhotosUrl)` is not applied.

I Have tried `CreateMap<User, UserDetailsDto>().Formember(dest.Mylistings.ListingPhotosUrl,src.Mylistings.Photos.Url)` but it seems that is not possible.

I Also tried this-> But no luck

```
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDetailsDto>();
                cfg.CreateMap<Listing, ListingSearchResultsDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ListingPhotosUrl, opt =>
            {
                opt.MapFrom(src => src.Photos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsMain).Url);
            });

            });

            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

The Code:

AutoMappperProfiles

```
 public AutoMapperProfiles()
        {
            CreateMap<Listing, ListingSearchResultsDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ListingPhotosUrl, opt =>
            {
                opt.MapFrom(src => src.Photos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsMain).Url);
            });           


            CreateMap<User, UserDetailsDto>();

            CreateMap<ListingPhoto, ListingPhotosDetailedDto>();
        }
```

User

```
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Listing> MyListings { get; set; }
    }
```

UserDetailsDto

```
public class UserDetailsDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ListingSearchResultsDto> MyListings { get; set;}
     }
```

Listing

```
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ListingPhoto> Photos { get; set; }
```

ListingSearchResultsDto

```
    public class ListingSearchResultsDto
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ListingPhotosUrl { get; set; }                    
    }
```

I am using `CreateMap<Listing, ListingSearchResultsDto>().Formember(des,src)` to manually map a destination property `ListingPhotosUrl`. I have another mapping `CreateMap<User, UserDetailsDto>()`. Inside `User` & `UsedetailsDto` classes i have a objects called `MyListings` of types `ICollection<Listing>` and `ICollection<ListingSearchResultsDto>` respectively. `MyListings` object is auto mapped correctly but `ListingPhotosUrl` manual mapping is not being applied. `CreateMap<Listing,ListingSearchResultsDto>.Formember(des,src))` manual mapping is working at top level, but not at deeper level inside `CreateMap<User, UserDetailsDto>()`, is there anyway to fix this? thanks

Comment: Is DI configured correctly? Check [the docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core).

Answer (score 0):

FIXED - Automapper was working fine. Issue in Entity Framework DbContext. I did not include the photos as related data in the EF Core method for loading USER data `GETUSER()`. It was working with EF Core method for loading LISTING `GetListing()` because i had an include for photos `Include(p => p.Photos)`.

After adding `.ThenInclude(p => p.Photos)` in `GetUser()`, the photos were returned with USER data and automapper successfully mapped User data and `ListingPhotosUrl` manual mapping was applied successfully.

Entity Framework Core DbContext:

```
public async Task<User> GetUser(int id)
{
    var user = await _context.Users
        .Include(a => a.Avatar)
        .Include(l => l.MyListings)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.Photos)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);

    return user;
}

public async Task<Listing> GetListing(int id)
{
    var listing = await _context.Listings
        .Include(p => p.Photos)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.id == id);

    return listing;
}
```